# Excluding specific values from pattern match

Tags: regex

The following regex captures IP addresses as well as DNS hostnames. 
What I'd like is to add some IPs to ignore, such as 1.0.0.0 and 0.0.0.0 for example.   I tried some negative lookahead without success.

`[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+`

for example :

www.google.com   255.255.255.255   1.0.0.0  stackoverflow.com    0.0.0.0

should match 3 out of 5 in that line

Any tips would be great.

edit :  I tried this, which somewhat works but also filters out other values such as 1.1.1.1  for example

`(?![1\.0\.0\.0]|[0\.0\.0\.0])[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+`

Comment: Should probably separate the IP addresses from the host names.

Comment: Something like this? https://regex101.com/r/8UXMzZ/1

Comment: thanks @CAustin . I'll also have a look at this !

Answer (score 1):

To find IP's and domains while ignoring IP's `1.0.0.0` and `0.0.0.0` and
validation ov Ipv4 and domain contains at least a letter, all wrapped inside
a white space boundary is thisr :

```
(?<!\S)(?!0{0,2}[01](?:\.0{1,3}){3})(?:(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:0{0,2}\d|0?[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}|(?=\S*[a-zA-Z])[\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)+)(?!\S)
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZPQS5K/1

Expanded

```
 (?<! \S )
 (?!                           # Not  0.0.0.0  or  1.0.0.0
      0{0,2} [01] 
      (?: \. 0{1,3} ){3}
 )
 (?:
      (?:                           # IP address
           0{0,2} \d 
        |  0? [1-9] \d 
        |  1 \d{2} 
        |  2 [0-4] \d 
        |  25 [0-5] 
      )
      (?:
           \. 
           (?:
                0{0,2} \d 
             |  0? [1-9] \d 
             |  1 \d{2} 
             |  2 [0-4] \d 
             |  25 [0-5] 
           )
      ){3}

   |                              # or 
      (?= \S* [a-zA-Z] )            # At least a letter
      [\w-]+                        # Domain
      (?: \. [\w-]+ )+
 )
 (?! \S )
```

Comment: wow.  that's impressive.  I appreciate that, I'll have to study it some more to understand it in depth.  Thank you !